# Sites copying content from wordpress.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I asked this question [Why is there a listen port difference between docker image wordpress:5 and wordpress:5-fpm?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/385262/why-is-there-a-listen-port-difference-between-docker-image-wordpress5-and-wordp)
 then noticed the content had been copied to https://www.sebastianbuza.com/2021/03/18/why-is-there-a-listen-port-difference-between-docker-image-wordpress5-and-wordpress5-fpm/. Some of the text was changed, even in the code blocks. For example, this:

```
wordpress:
  image: wordpress:5
  #image: wordpress:5-fpm
  container_name: wordpress
  restart: always
```

became:

```
wordpress:
  picture: wordpress:5
  #picture: wordpress:5-fpm
  container_name: wordpress
  restart: all the time
```

As though the English had been translated and then translated back, but poorly. What's SE's view on this sort of copying?

Edit: I've since deleted the original question. It was a pretty obvious error.

Comment: The site should be reported. Look here for instructions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377238/2199525

Comment: This is quite common, there's even chrome extensions to reroute you to the original questions

Comment: Thanks all. Duly reported.

Answer (score 5):

Note, I am not a copyright lawyer by any means. The following is simply my interpretation.

Questions and Answers posted to StackExchange are public and covered by [Creative Commons 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). This generally means that anyone can...

> **Share** — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>
> **Adapt** — remix, transform, and build upon the material
> for any purpose, even commercially.

The user must provide some form of reasonable attribution. At the bottom of their post is a Source Link, linking back to the original question, which I believe covers this case. For more information, I would recommend reading the [StackExchange Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public).

Comment: I think there's more to that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/report-high-google-ranking-stack-exchange-content-copiers-here. And the site probably should be reported. Instructions here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377238/2199525

Comment: Hard for me to say. They're not claiming to be the author, nor are they using the StackExchange name ( as the linked meta topics issue suggests ). They are linking back to the source and not necessarily trying to "overtake" StackExchange.  Good find though. No harm in reporting it and letting StackExchange decide.